# Sass: Storing @content into list for use later in another mixin?

Tags: sass

I am trying to store the `@content` directive from one mixin into a list so that I can use it later in another mixin. I am getting errors when I try this. Anyone know if this is possible?

Example is a simplified version of what I am doing, but basically I want to create custom breakpoint classes but without having all of the extra markup from the media query on every class.

Heres what I've got:

```css
$breakpoints: ((sm, 320px), (md, 780px), (lg, 960px));
$all: ();

@mixin push($name) {
  $content: (@content);
  $all: append($all, ($name, $content));
}

@mixin printAll() {
  @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    $breakpointName: nth($breakpoint, 1);
    $breakpointSize: nth($breakpoint, 2);
    @media only screen and (min-width: $breakpointSize) {
      @each $item in $all {
        $className: nth($item, 1);
        $content: nth($item, 2);
        #{$className}-#{$breakpointName} {
          #{$content};
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include push(color-red){ color: red; }
@include push(color-green){ color: green; }
@include push(color-blue){ color: blue; }
@include push(totally-crazy){
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
  border-top: solid 5px brown;
  border-left: solid 5px gray;
  border-right: solid 5px blue;
  border-bottom: solid 5px yellow;
}

@include printAll();
```

So basically I want to output something like:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  //all custom classes with -sm suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {
  //all custom classes with -md suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  //all custom classes with -lg suffix here
}
```

INSTEAD of:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  //first pushed class with -sm suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {
  //first pushed class with -md suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  //first pushed class with -lg suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  //second pushed class with -sm suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {
  //second pushed class with -md suffix here
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  //second pushed class with -lg suffix here
}

etc..
```

Example here:

http://sassmeister.com/gist/10332360